# Is there an organisation behind the Mishna Yomis cycle?

Tags: torah-study, mishna, organizations

There is a fairy popular seder to finish *shisa sedrei mishna* every 5.8 years, by doing two mishnayos every day. I know that there is one pretty much standardized cycle as every calendar that I've seen is in sync.

This cycle is nearing its close, and I'm wondering if there is any organisation behind it. (Similar to how the Agudah is behind *Daf Yomi*, and how Dirshu is behind Mishna Berurah Yomis)

## Is there an organisation behind the Mishna Yomis cycle?

Comment: Seems like Jews not Judaism.

Comment: @mevaqesh - What does that mean?

Comment: That this is not clearly a question about Judaism itself, and looks like a question about Jews which is off topic. @ibid

Comment: @mevaqesh - I was under the impression that questions about "the culture of the Jewish Religion" are [on topic](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1951/11667).

Answer (score 1):

Irgun HaMishna Hayomit.
 בברכת "מרבה תורה - מרבה חיים"!
קביעותא - המפעל ללימוד המשנה וההלכה היומית
להנצחת ששת המיליונים

072-272-0000
 you can receive by Email a booklet with questions and answers on the Mishna and Halacha yomit. You must to send a mail to
office@kviuta.org and make a request to receive. the booklet is an attached pdf.
[המעונין לקבל קובץ עם הלימוד מידי יום נא לשלוח בקשה למייל זה :office@kviuat.org](http://%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%9C%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%9C%20%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A5%20%D7%A2%D7%9D%20%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%20%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D%20%D7%A0%D7%90%20%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%97%20%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9C%20%D7%96%D7%94%20:office@kviuat.org)
The link is [here](http://www.ladaat.info/Gilionot/20160402/[2236]%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%90_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99.pdf)

 It is very good.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Mishna Yomis calendar]

The top of the calendar for mishna yomit is shown in the screen shot. 
This tells you the current contacts for getting the calendar and who founded it and in memory of whom.

There is also a website, http://www.mishnahyomit.com/.

But there is no evidence in either place of the organisation that publishes the website or the calendar.

Comment: So your answer sums up to "I don't know of one"?